What is the typical cache size of MMU paging-structures?
Typical TLB sizes are well known for different page sizes (4KB, 2MiB, etc) however there is very little known about the page table cache sizes (E.g. Paging-Structure Caches from Sec 4.10.3 Vol 3A of the Intel Software Developer Manual). In addition to the TLB and PDE, a processor may cache partial page walks in memory. Either per level cache size (intel) or the unified page table cache size (amd). I skimmed through Intel's Software Developer Manual Vol 3 Chapter 4 and could not find answers for any of the following questions.
I am interested in knowing the following for a real microarchitecture (E.g. Skylake):

What is the typical cache size?
Are the cache sizes same across levels? How are they partitioned?
Does the number of entries per cache level change with the page granularity (4 KiB, 2 MiB)
Finally, what is the caching policy used? LRU?


This is going to be entirely processor dependent.

Yes @user3344003. I am not interested in exact numbers. To begin with just learning about the order of these cache sizes across levels would be helpful.
